# how to install v8 firebase and delete v9 with npm

Tags: javascript, firebase, npm

how to install v8 firebase and delete v9 using npm?

I am using Firebase in ReactJS and don't know how to do it.

```
npm install firebase
```

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/compat/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/compat/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/compat/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
```

Comment: A lot of how to do so depends on how you installed v9 in the first place. Can you edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show how you installed Firebase for your React app?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i am edit my question

Comment: Why do you want to downgrade from v9 to v8?

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB I'm tired I don't know what to do I know v8 version.I'm tired I don't know what to do I know v8 version. please

Comment: Its already answered by @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 2):

Since you installed with:

```
npm install firebase
```

That installs the latest version, which you can then uninstall with:

```
npm uninstall firebase
```

After that you can install a specific version of the SDK with:

```
npm install firebase@<version>
```

So for the most recent v8 version, that'd be:

```
npm install firebase@8.10.0
```

---

If you want to keep using the old, namespaced API syntax, there is no need to downgrade though. You can instead use the `compat` paths of the v9 version, as shown in the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade):

```
// v9 compat packages are API compatible with v8 code
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```